# JSON string splitting / parsing

Tags: iphone, json

I have a string that looks like this:

```
"[{"ImageTagID":78,"Xpixel":408,"Ypixel":69,"Xpercent":17,"Ypercent":68,"ImageID":45617}]"
```

How do i break it up to pieces?

Thanks,

Comment: 1. This has absolutely nothing to do with Xcode. 2. You haven't tried googling, which is bad.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dictionary. There are keys and values in a dictionary. If you need a particular value, you must get it using the key.

In iOS it is done this way,

```
int tagID = [yourdictionary objectForKey:@"ImageTagID"];
```

Hope this helps you start. If you have more questions, do ask me.

Splitting a string:

Example: `NSArray *stringArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString: @","];`

Comment: I wish it was a dictionary. It is a string. I logged its class and it's __NSCFString. I know i should get it as a dictionary from the WS but sadly i didn't. Is there a way to split a string?

Comment: updated again.. have a look...